# Array in Excel Anylogic

Tags: arrays, excel, anylogic

I want to safe the values of an array in Excel. The 4 values are in "double[] polparams" and i want to have each values in the same row and 4 columns. Thanks for help!

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42fBP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final WeightedObservedPoints obs = new WeightedObservedPoints();

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i +=2)
{
obs.add(data[i], data[i+1]);
}

final PolynomialCurveFitter fitter = PolynomialCurveFitter.create(3);

return fitter.fit(obs.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < polparams.length ; i++ )
 excelFile.setCellValue(polparams[i], 1, 1, i);
```

Comment: when i do this i get the error "polparams cannot be resolved to a variable" 

Do you know what the mistake is?

Comment: Where are you using the code I suggested?

Comment: at the end of the Code...do i have to use it directly after 
double[] polparams = polfitter(data); ?

Comment: Not sure what this does "polfitter(data)"

Comment: see new answer for code of polfitter(data)...i don't know how to write it in comment correctly

The Code of polfitter(data) is written in a stand alone function

Comment: when i do it directly after Double[] polparams = polfitter(data) i get the error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 4"

Comment: It means that the array size is less than 4. Try replacing 4 in the for loop by polparams.length (refer to edited solution)